# weblate connect to aws rds postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, weblate

I'm trying to connect weblate to external rds postgres database.
I'm using docker compose file that run weblate container. To this container I add the environment variables to connect to rds postgres.
The weblate container doesn't connect to rds postgres and give me this error:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "XXXX.rds.amazonaws.com", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

but if I try to connect to rds postgres from inside the weblate container via cli, it works.

docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  weblate:
    image: weblate/weblate
    tmpfs:
      - /app/cache
    volumes:
      - weblate-data:/app/data
    env_file:
      - ./environment
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: XXXX
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_DATABASE: mydb
      POSTGRES_HOST: XXX.rds.amazonaws.com
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
The problem was **the char $ inside password**.

Maybe the library used to connect to postgres has a bug or, simple, not allowed $ in password string.
When I removed that char it works.

Answer (score 0):

It tries to connect as `postgres` user while your configuration states `myuser`. Maybe the `./environment` file overrides that?

Comment: myuser was just an example. Thanks for the answer